# Read data from excel and insert into HIVE

Tags: pandas, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm reading data from Excel sheet using pandas. I need to insert data into HIVE using pyspark.

```
sparkConf = SparkConf().setAppName("App")
sc = SparkContext(conf = sparkConf)

sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)

excel_file = pd.ExcelFile("export_n_moreExportData10846.xls")
for sheet_name in excel_file.sheet_names:
try:
    df = pd.read_excel(excel_file, header=None, squeeze=True, sheet_name=sheet_name)
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        if row.notnull().all():
            data = df.iloc[(i+1):].reset_index(drop=True)
                data.columns = list(df.iloc[i])
                break
        for c in data.columns:
        data[c] = pd.to_numeric(data[c], errors='ignore')
    print data #I need to insert this data into HIVE

except:
    continue
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save your Pandas dataframe using the following code, providing the column types are compatible with Spark:

```
tablename = 'your_table_name'
df_spark = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data)

#Remove spaces from your column names
columns_with_spaces = filter(lambda x:' ' in x,df.columns)
for column in columns_with_spaces:
     old_column = column
     new_column = column.replace(' ','_')
     df_spark =  df_spark.withColumnRenamed(old_column , new_column)

#Save to Hive
df_spark.write.mode('overwrite').saveAsTable(tableName)
```

Comment: 18/01/22 17:05:16 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database global_temp, returning NoSuchObjectException

Comment: That is expected behaviour.  If the default database doesn't exist the metastore gives a warning and a default database is created.:https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-14067

Comment: 18/01/22 17:07:32 ERROR CreateDataSourceTableAsSelectCommand: Failed to write to table mytablename
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Attribute name "TC Title" contains invalid character(s) among " ,;{}()\n\t=". Please use alias to rename it.;

Comment: Sorry, your column `TC Title` has a space in it, you will need to rename that column before you can save it into Hive, for example `TC_Title`

Comment: Is there any easy way to rename? OR is there any way to create table using columns first and then insert data into it

Comment: I added code to my answer to rename all columns with spaces

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163638/discussion-between-krishna-and-jaco).

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the HadoopOffice library, it offers Excel reading/writing with many features on major Big Data platforms (MR, Hive, Flink, Spark...):
https://github.com/ZuInnoTe/hadoopoffice/wiki